# Can't pass #, ", & in $_GET

Tags: php, mysql

I am providing a very simple test dataset and my code to try to resolve this issue. If the question has been asked before I have not been able to find it.  I'm self-taught from books and the web so this is not slick programming. I hope I am providing enough information.

The dataset consists of one table ‘comments’ with fields id (autoincrement), name (text), comments (textarea), date, display (enum)
The mysql connection collation and all text and text area fields are set to  utf8_general_ci

```
The <head> includes 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
```

All post and get statements are escaped as follows

```
$fieldname =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['fieldname']);
```

My code successfully enters the problem characters into the database and they are retrieved successfully if I just want to display them, however in the real world I need to vet user entries to ensure they are suitable for public viewing and I also need to be able to edit them.  When I open my comments-edit page, anything after an & in a field disappears and if there is a # or " in any field nothing is retrieved at all.

First the comments-admin.php page:

```
   <?php
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
    ?>
        <table width="100%"><tr><td>
        <b>ID:</b></td><td>
        <b>Name:</b></td><td align="left">
        <b>Comments:</b></td><td>
        <b>Date Posted:</b></td><td>
        <b>Display:</b></td></tr><tr><td>
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<tr valign="top" ><td>';
        echo  $row['id'] . '</td><td>';
        echo  $row['name'] . '</td><td>'; 
        echo  $row['comments'] . '</td><td>'; 
        echo  $row['date'] . '</td><td>'; 
        echo  $row['display'] . '</td><td>'; 
        echo  '<td><a href="comments-edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . 
              '&amp;name=' . $row['name'] . 
              '&amp;comments=' . $row['comments'] . 
              '&amp;date=' . $row['date'] . 
              '&amp;display=' . $row['display'] . 
              '">Edit</a></td></tr>';
          }
          ?>
          </table>
```

This results in a table which looks like this (without the decoration).

```
ID: Name:     Comments:                    Date Posted:  Display:
12  Fred    Just wanted to say "Thank You"  2015-11-04    No        Edit
11  Ricky   I live at #2, Anywhere Street.  2015-11-04    No        Edit
9   Ethel   Why can't I make this work!     2015-10-24   Yes        Edit
4   Lucy    Went to A&W today               2015-04-23   Yes        Edit
```

"Edit opens my comments-edit.php form.  In this example the only one which will open correctly is #9.  #'s 11 & 12 will not retrieve anything at all, and #4 will not have anything after the &.

The code for comments-edit follows:

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
  or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

 if (isset($_GET['id']) &&
   isset($_GET['name']) && 
   isset($_GET['comments']) && 
   isset($_GET['date'])) 
{

// Grab the data from the GET
    $id = ( $_GET['id']);
    $name =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['name']);
    $comments =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['comments']);
    $date =  ( $_GET['date']);
}
else if (isset($_POST['id']) && 
    isset($_POST['name']) && 
    isset($_POST['comments']) && 
    isset($_POST['date']) && 
    isset($_POST['display']))  
{
// Grab the data from the POST
    $id =  ( $_POST['id']);
    $name =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['name']);
    $comments =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['comments']);
    $date =  ( $_POST['date']);
    $display =  ( $_POST['display']);
    }

   <form class="gap" method="post" action="comments-update.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="ud_id" value="<?php echo "$id;" ?>" />
<p class="gap"><b>Select "Yes" before clicking "Edit Data" to confirm any changes</b></p>
<input type="radio" name="confirm" value="Yes" /> Yes 
<input type="radio" name="confirm" value="No" checked="checked" /> No 
<input type="submit" value="Edit Data" name="update" /><br />   

<label class="appsm">Comment Date:</label>
<input type="text" size="30" name="ud_date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" 

<label class="appsm">ID:</label>
<input type="text" size="5" name="ud_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

<label class="appsm">Display:</label>
      <select id="ud_display" name="ud_display">
        <option value="yes" <?php if (!empty($display) && $display == 'yes') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Yes</option>
        <option value="no" <?php if (!empty($display) && $display == 'no') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>No</option>
      </select><br />

<label class="appsm">Name:</label>
<input type="text" size="50" name="ud_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
<br />
<label class="appsm">comments:</label>
<textarea name="ud_comments" wrap="physical" class="left" cols="105" rows="2">
<?php echo stripslashes($comments); ?></textarea>

</form>
```

I'm sure I've missed something very simple and I've searched my books and the web but I have not found an answer to this specific issue.  I would really like to be able to remove all the warnings not to use these characters from my real websites, especially since users rarely read the instructions.

Comment: You need to URLencode the comments. The `&` in the comment makes it a new parameter in your get request. You also should look into XSS injections and preventing them. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, you need to encode things that are passed in the URL.

But my question is, why are you passing all that info to the second page when you can get it out of the database? Also changed your code to use a [heredoc block](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead of all those `echo()` statements. It's a handy way to make your code more readable. Finally, outputting data to HTML requires you to escape it with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). I used [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to quickly escape the entire database record.

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
?>
    <table width="100%"><tr><td>
    <b>ID:</b></td><td>
    <b>Name:</b></td><td align="left">
    <b>Comments:</b></td><td>
    <b>Date Posted:</b></td><td>
    <b>Display:</b></td></tr><tr><td>
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $row = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $row);
        echo <<< HTML
<tr valign="top">
    <td>$row[id]</td>
    <td>$row[name]</td>
    <td>$row[comments]</td>
    <td>$row[date]</td>
    <td>$row[display]</td> 
    <td><a href="comments-edit.php?id=$row[id]">Edit</a></td>
</tr>

HTML;
      }
      ?>
      </table>
```

Your second file. Note that $_POST and $_GET are both combined into the superglobal $_REQUEST, though you should really know how your own page is going to be sending data. Again HTML output is escaped.

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    $id = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
if (!isset($_REQUEST['id']) || !$row) {
    // you should do something in this case
    return false;
}
$id = htmlspecialchars($row['id']);
$name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
$comments = htmlspecialchars($row['comments']);
$date = htmlspecialchars($row['date']);
$display = htmlspecialchars($row['display']);
?>

<form class="gap" method="post" action="comments-update.php">
<input type="hidden" name="ud_id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
...
```

Comment: Thank you miken32.  The reason for passing info into an edit page is that several different people manage different aspects of the websites and they don't have direct access to the database.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your comment.  I do it this way  because that is what the first book that I used did and it works for me and the other users who know less about this stuff than I do.  Also, my real tables have numerous text fields which are easier to deal with in a new form.  Is there something other than (int)$_REQUEST['id'] that would work with an alphanumeric primary key?  I tried replacing int with varchar but just get an error message...else I can add an integer primary to those tables.

Comment: This is my point, it doesn't matter what's in your database. You pass the record ID so the receiving page can take whatever it wants out of the database. You should not use anything but a column of type SERIAL for a record ID unless you have a very very good reason. If you need a non-numeric record ID passed, you'll need to get into prepared statements and paramaterized queries.

Comment: Sigh!  What seemed intuitive to my human brain at the time isn't to a machine which thinks in 0's and 1's.  I've given myself a little extra work but in the end it's an easy fix.  You help has been invaluable.  Thank you again